# How to delete the consecutive duplicate elements from list also reflect that in another list in same data frame pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, list, memory-efficient

I have a data frame like this

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 32 | [1,2,2,3,4] | [a,b,c,d,e] |
| 35 | [5,5,7,7,7,8] | [q,w,e,r,t,y] |

so there are the repeating elements in the B column that need to remove the second, third and so on occurrences and similarly, the elements in the C columns also get deleted with the same positions as B

the final result will be:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 32 | [1,2,3,4] | [a,b,d,e] |
| 35 | [5,7,8] | [q,e,y] |

it's in a pandas data frame.

Comment: How is column C related to column B?

Comment: @TalhaTayyab both lists are associated with each other and if we are losing the data from the first list we need to remove the elements from the second list also to maintain the associativity (just a use case for me)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) by both columns, then convert `df.index` to column `df['index']` and remove duplicates per `index` and `B` column by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and last aggregate by `index` with `A` column with `list`:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'A': [32, 35],
        'B': [[1, 2, 2, 3, 4], [5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 8]],
        'C': [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y']]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)



df1 = (df.explode(['B','C'])
         .reset_index()
         .drop_duplicates(['index','B'])
         .groupby(['index', 'A'])
         .agg(list)
         .reset_index(level=1)
         .rename_axis(None))

print (df1)
    A             B             C
0  32  [1, 2, 3, 4]  [a, b, d, e]
1  35     [5, 7, 8]     [q, e, y]
```

If values in `A` column are always unique:

```
df2 = (df.explode(['B','C'])
         .drop_duplicates(['A','B'])
         .groupby(['A'])
         .agg(list)
         .reset_index())

print (df2)
```

EDIT: Solution for oldier pandas version:

```
df1 = (df[['A']].join(df[['B','C']].apply(lambda x: x.explode()))
         .reset_index()
         .drop_duplicates(['index','B'])
         .groupby(['index', 'A'])
         .agg(list)
         .reset_index(level=1)
         .rename_axis(None))

print (df1)
```

Comment: Why does index suddenly appear?

Comment: @Nineteendo - If use `reset_index` it create column from `df.index` and column name is `index`

Comment: if we don't want to make any column as an index, then?

Comment: @codex - Then use second solution, but need unique values in `A`

Comment: OK, I think it's now perfect. +1

Comment: Could you add this at the start? It makes the code testable. ```import pandas as pd
data = {
 'A': [32, 35],
 'B': [[1, 2, 2, 3, 4], [5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 8]],
 'C': [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y']]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)```

Comment: ValueError: column must be a scalar

Comment: @codex - It is oldier pandas version, can you check `EDIT` ? Or upgrade pandas.

Comment: @jezrael just upgraded and checked still the same, i have 1.1.3

Comment: @codex - I check docs - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html and multilist parameter is possible in `New in version 1.3.0`

Comment: @jezrael EDIT version worked, Still Don't know why the latest version of code is not working, btw thanks a lot for all your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Not very pandish, but trying to optimize memory used:

```py
import numpy as np

# For each row, compute the indices of the first occurrence of each value in column B
df['_indices_to_keep'] = df.B.map(
        lambda x: np.unique(x, return_index=True)[1] if x else None,
)

# Keep only values in columns B and C corresponding to the previously found positions
for c in ('B', 'C'):
    df[c] = df.apply(lambda r: [r[c][i] for i in r['_indices_to_keep']] if r[c] else None, axis=1)

# Drop the temporary column with the indices
df.drop(columns=['_indices_to_keep'], inplace=True)
```

The result is:

```bash
    A             B             C
0  32  [1, 2, 3, 4]  [a, b, d, e]
1  35     [5, 7, 8]     [q, e, y]
```

Answer (score 0):

Short solution basing on [`np.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) and [`np.take`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) routines:

```
def drop_dups(r):
    vals, idx_start = np.unique(r['B'], return_index=True)
    r['B'], r['C'] = vals, np.take(r['C'], idx_start)
    return r

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df[['B', 'C']] = df[['B', 'C']].apply(drop_dups, axis=1)
print(df)
```

The output:

```
   A             B             C
0  32  [1, 2, 3, 4]  [a, b, d, e]
1  35     [5, 7, 8]     [q, e, y]
```

Comment: this may not preserve the order of the elements

Comment: @codex, No, it will reflect the order, due to `return_index` parameter.

Comment: I don't know why, but for my use case when I used this concept the order got changed, in C column I have time stamps

Comment: @codex, share a testable fragment of your dataframe (with those timestamps), I'll check